# Python: What is wrong with my "Try Again" button function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()


display_height = 800#display width and height
display_width = 1000

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)#defining colours
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (127, 179, 213)
peru = (139,119,101)
beige = (250,250,225)
lightb = (245,222,179)
bg = (255,248,220)
grey_slate = (50,50,50)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Algebra Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, white)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',50)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def message_display2(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',30)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/3))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def Try_Again1(msg,x,y,w,h,inac,act,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, act,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "Try Again":
                Addition_loop1()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inac,(x,y,w,h))


def home_button(msg,x,y,w,h,inac,act,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, act,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "Home":
                game_intro()

    else:
        pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, inac,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)



def button(msg,x,y,w,h,inac,act,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()


    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, act,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "Addition":
                Addition_loop1()
            elif action == "Subtraction":
                Subtraction_loop1()
            elif action == "Multiplication":
                Multiplication_loop1()
            elif action == "Division":
                Division_loop1()
            elif action == "Option 1":
                incorrect_loop1()



    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inac,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def incorrect_loop1():
    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        message_display2("You are Incorrect")
        Try_Again1("Try Again",25,25,150,50,peru,grey_slate,"Try Again")
        pygame.display.update()


def Addition_loop1():
    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        home_button("Home",25,25,150,50,peru,grey_slate,"Home")
        addition = pygame.image.load("addition.jpg")
        gameDisplay.blit(addition,(330,50))
        button("Option 1",50,500,200,50,peru,black,"Option 1")







        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)





def Subtraction_loop1():
    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        home_button("Home",25,25,150,50,peru,grey_slate,"Home")



        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


def Multiplication_loop1():
    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        home_button("Home",25,25,150,50,peru,grey_slate,"Home")




        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

def Division_loop1():
    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        home_button("Home",25,25,150,50,peru,grey_slate,"Home")



        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(grey_slate)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',50)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("The Algebra Game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/14))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Addition",250,125,500,85,peru,black,"Addition")
        button("Subtraction",250,250,500,85,peru,black,"Subtraction")
        button("Multiplication",250,375,500,85,peru,black,"Multiplication")
        button("Division",250,500,500,85,peru,black,"Division")

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)



    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_intro()
pygame.quit()
quit
```

Hi, I am experiencing some difficulties getting a "Try_Again1" button function to work, it is currently not showing up text or taking me to the desired page (Addition_loop1) once clicked, the button is also flickering in and out of view from the screen when running. I am using Python 3.5 (32-bit). Any help with my issue would be much appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: Just wondering if anyone has had the time to look at this, I know we are all poor on time. I realise that ultimately I may have to delete this portion of my code. I have only been coding for a few months now and would really appreciate any support I receive. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: I have added a clock.tick(60) to the end of the incorrect_loop() and the button has decreased flashing but it still remains flickering in and out of the display. The button still takes me to the wrong page when clicked.  Please has anyone any thoughts on my code. I would appreciate any feedback. Thank you in advance.